# Linq to objects very slow compared to dataview

Tags: performance, linq, poco

I'm a big fan of Linq for typeing, clarity and brevity. But I'm finding it very slow to search for matching records compared to the old dataview by a factor of some 2000 times!

I am writing an app to backup large sets of files - 500,000 files and 500 gb of data. I have created a manifest of files in the backup set and compare the files in the directory with those in the manifest documenting what's been backed up already. This way I know which files have changed and so need to be copied.

The slow step is this one:

`var matchingMEs = from m in manifest
                    where m.FullName == fi.FullName
                    select m;`

where `manifest = List<ManifestEntry>` and `ManifestEntry` is a relatively simple POCO.

Overall performance is 17-18 records per second.

When I use a dataview:

`DataView vueManifest = new DataView(dt, "", "FullName", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);`

then in the loop find the matching manifest entries with a .FindRows:

`matchingMEs = vueManifest.FindRows(fi.FullName);`

... then I'm getting some 35,000 files per second throughput!

Is this normal? I can't believe that Linq comes at such a price. Is it the Linq or the objects that slow things down?

(btw, I tried using a `Dictionary` and a `SortedList` as well as the `List<ManifestEntries>` and they all gave about the same result.)

Comment: If you are getting the same bad result with a Dictionary, I assume you are initializing it not correctly. Please show the corresponding code. Additionally, please show the impementation of `m.FullName`. Of what type is `fi`? More: `FindRows` returns all matching rows. Your `foreach` loop over this result doesn't do any search. In contrast to this, LINQ uses deferred execution and will perform the search inside your `foreach` loop. To correctly compare the runtimes, you need to compare the LINQ `foreach` with the duration of the call to `FindRows` + the `foreach` loop.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. What is ManifestEntry.FullName doing? Is it loading from a file?

Comment: I think you first run linq query then data grideview query, in this step, all files loaded so data grid works fast but if you reverse execution path you will get another result.

Comment: Hey Daniel, Cameron; m.FullName is just a string in an object: `public string FullName { get; set; }`. The main loop `foreach (FileInfo fi in Files)` is around this matching code so both the linq query or the FindRows are in the same conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Your DataView is sorting by fullname and hence FindRows can jump straight to the correct record(s), whereas your linq query has to iterate through list until it reaches the correct record(s).
This will definitely be noticeable if you have 500,000 entries.

Assuming fullname is unique, then when you switched to using a dictionary, I would suspect you are still iterating through it using a similar linq query, something like

```
var matchingME = (from m in manifest where m.Key == fi.FullName select m).Single();
```

whereas you should be using

```
var matchingME = manifest[fi.FullName] ;
```

Comment: You legend @sgmoore! That's (almost) exactly what I had minus the `.single()`. Unfortunately I've ripped out the code for the objects now and replaced with datatable. I realized the dictionary solution wouldn't work for me as the file could be in the manifest more than once - i.e. FullName may not be unique - in the case of deleted and modified copies of files. So even with your solution, I'd still be stuck. Does this still leave linq high and dry?

Comment: @RichieRich You ask 'Does this still leave linq high and dry?' Well, I'm not an expert on how linq to objects is implemented, so not really qualified to answer that question, but I would not use it in this situation.  If I started from a List<ManifestEntry> , I would probably use ToDictionary (if the key is unique) otherwise I'd use ToLookup.